# lim approaching 0 with 2 lims

Tags: limits

A bit confused on this problem I have, trying to see how to solve it, I would post what I have done, but I literally just have no idea what to do. The 2 lims are what's throwing me off, anyways here's the problem:

$$\lim_{x\to-4} (x\lim_{x\to0}f(x)) = 2$$

Trying to see how to solve, don't necessarily need the answer but just a general guidance would be fine.

Comment: In its current state, this don't make any sense to me

Comment: Use a different variable for the inner limit.

Comment: $x\lim_{y\to 0}f(y)$ yes, $x\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ no.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the notation. The variable $x$ occurs in two contexts. This makes the notation bogus. You could either write
$$\lim_{x\to-4}x\lim_{t\to0} f(t) = 2$$
Either the limit of $f$ doesn't exist at $0$ or we can extend $f$ to $0$ with a finite number independent of $x$, so $\lim_{x\to-4}x \tilde f(0) = -4\tilde f(0) = 2$ telling us that $\lim_{t\to0}f(t) = \tilde f(0) = -\frac12$, or it says
$$\lim_{x\to-4}x\lim_{t\to0} f(x) = 2$$
Wich simplifies to
$$\lim_{x\to-4} xf(x) = 2$$

Comment: Your last line does not actually follow from what you've written above.

Comment: @bashfuloctopus How is $\lim_{t\to0} f(x) \ne f(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate what's in the parentheses first. 
$$\lim\limits_{x\to-4}(x\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)) = 2$$

becomes

$$(\lim\limits_{x\to-4}x)(\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)) = -4\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x) =2$$

Comment: This is bogus. By moving parentheses, you change the matematical meaning.

Comment: The inner limit is evaluated first, so (paraphrasing) there's no $x$ dependence left once the limit of $f(x)$ is evaluated, except for the linear multiplying term.

Comment: I don't know who taught you that, but that's wrong. See all comments to the question so far.

Comment: Assume $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists. Indeed, it must, since a right hand value is given. Call this limit $b$. Then 
$$\lim_{x\to-4}(x\lim_{x\to0}f(x)) = \lim_{x\to-4}(xb) = -4b = 2$$
So $b = -\frac{1}{2}$ and we justify my original statement. No need for changing dummy variables, either.

Comment: There is no such language feature as shadowing in mathematics. Double binding the variable $x$ to both limits is illegal. Therefor the equation makes no sense without altering it.

Comment: Unfortunately, there exist questions which can be better stated. We still know what they mean; we still know how to work with them. This doesn't invalidate our solutions. It only slacks on the rigour a little.